# SQL foreign key between projects in different VS solutions

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I want to split the development of our data warehouse solution in to manageable Visual Studio projects that can be edited independently and grow organically. I have developed a project that contains all the conformed dimensions like Date in one solution. Can I reference my Date dimension from a different solution where I need to include a foreign key? I have tried to reference the dacpac containing the conformed dimension but this does not work as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short, you can not create an FK referencing a table in another database, both tables should be located in the same database. FK is a database object, not a server object.

You can however use triggers to manage FK, which is of course not the best solution.

> FOREIGN KEY constraints can reference only tables within the same database on the same server. Cross-database referential integrity must be implemented through triggers. For more information, see CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

---

Based on your comment (see below), here are some thoughts:

> You have several good arguments. Though I was looking for a way where we could model several business processes in parallel this might not be an option. It seems that the only option might be to have one big project and then handle how to manage more than one developer working in the solution at the same time - thanks

- One database = one project
- Enforce communication between team members
- Update your VCS policies to minimize problems
- Educate the team members about possible problems and their workarounds
- - Including deployment options
- Provide sufficient resources (including dev workstations) and use local instances for development
- Build an SIT (integration) environment where you can test changes and how they behave during deployment.
- Build a shared DEV environment which is used to merge the work of your team members
- Commit/push files into CVS which are considered as done. Commit/push regularly
- Route tasks to minimize conflicts (if a team member has something to do with object A, try to route all tasks related to object A to that developer or postpone the second change until the first one is done)
- If you use dacpac for deployment, include the configuration file (tested in SIT env) next to the dacpac file. (SIT should reflect the production environment when you are testing the deployment)

And again: Enforce communication inside and outside the team. This is the key.

Comment: I am aware that you cannot create FK between databases. In this case each VS project holds a subset of tables for the same destination database. In short the projects are being deployed to the same database.

Comment: Are you sure, that this is a good idea? The manifest file will contain only a subset of the tables and makes virtually impossible to perform some actions. Furthermore the dacpac files are considered as a database when you try to reference it in VS, it won't let you create the FK. Do you really have to create several independent solutions? You can organize your objects in VS using folders. (And yes, I am aware that a DWH has lots of objects)

Comment: You have several good arguments. Though I was looking for a way where we could model several business processes in parallel this might not be an option. It seems that the only option might be to have one big project and then handle how to manage more than one developer working in the solution at the same time - thanks

Comment: @PeterLarsen Sorry for the late reply, please check the updates in the answer.

Comment: "One database = one project"
This isn't really good advice, there are loads of scenarios where you would want to have one database spread across separate projects.

Comment: I'd be tempted to ignore the advice to use CVS too.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've managed these situations using separate *projects* in a single *solution*. Clearly the main goal is to avoid merge conflicts between the developers, with this arrangement the only place this should happen is in the solution file, which should be pretty rare.

There are a couple of things to be careful of here:

- The reference must be of type "Same database"
- The reference needs to be in the direction Fact -> Dimension
- When you deploy the "Fact" project, you need to be sure to specify the option to "Include Composite Objects". This is the default in Visual Studio.
- Circular references are not allowed. If you have these the workaround (very briefly, google for more) is to create a "parent" project with references to both "sides" of the "circle".

That said, it is also possible to create a foreign key to a referenced dacpac, rather than a database project. Again the reference needs to be in the direction Fact -> Dimension. You will also need to give some thought to your build process as in effect you are taking a *binary* dependency on the "Dimensions" dacpac. You can also add the dacpac to the referencing project (I tend to create a folder for these) so it ends up in the same place in source control).

In case it helps, I have created a solution that demonstrates both techniques and shared it here: https://github.com/gavincampbell-dev-example-repos/FKsToReferencedDacpacs